# time picker dialog, wrong time. alarm manager, fires alarm immediately

Tags: android

first question: I'm trying to get the current time in order to set the default time of the time picker dialog, but it doesn't give the correct time, I'll paste the code.

second question: the alarm fires instantly, what could be the problem?

there is one text view, and three buttons .
the text view shows the saying.
first button to show timepicker dialog.
second button to change the textview text.
third button to set the alarm using the time that was previously saved in a variable using time picker dialog from the first button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    // declare our view variables
    private TextView mSayingTextView;
    private TextView mMainTextView;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private Button mAlarmButton;
    private Button mSetTimeButton;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=0;
    public int hour,minute;//users` selection
    private int mHour,mMinute;//first values appear
    long timeInMillis;

    public MainActivity(){
        //assign current time values
        final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Assign the views from the layout file to the corresponding variables
        mSayingTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        mMainTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.abbTextView);
        mNextButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxtButton);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mAlarmButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.alarmButton);
        mAlarmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSetTimeButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.intentBtn);
        mSetTimeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


      //Register time picker dialog listener
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min){
            hour=hourOfDay;
            minute=min;
            timeInMillis=hour*60*60*1000 + minute*60*1000;
            mSetTimeButton.setText("Time now :"+mHour+":"+mMinute);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener,mHour,mMinute,false);
    }

    public void scheduleAlarm(){
       // Long time=new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+1*60*1000;
        Long time = timeInMillis;
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,intentAlarm,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm scheduled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.nxtButton:
                // do your code
                String[] sayings = {
                        "saying1" ,
                        "saying2"
                        ,
                        "saying3"
                };

                String saying="";

                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomNumber=randomGenerator.nextInt(sayings.length);
                saying=sayings[randomNumber];

                mSayingTextView.setText(saying);
                break;

            case R.id.alarmButton:
                scheduleAlarm();
                break;

            case R.id.intentBtn:
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

code in the alarm receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int duration=Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast.makeText(context,"alarm set",duration).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating alarm to a past time. Then system fires alarm immediately. Your `timeInMillis` parameter is wrong. You set only hour and minute in millis. You should also set day, month, year. Change your `onTimeSet` function of `TimePickerDialog` to that:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min){
    hour=hourOfDay;
    minute=min;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    mSetTimeButton.setText("Time now :"+mHour+":"+mMinute);
}
```

I used `Calendar` for setting also day, month and year to `timeInMillis`.

Also your `TimePickerDialog` is not set to current time. `mHour` and `mMinute` parameters are not set because of the override method `protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)`. You should write a function which can call after `mHour` and `mMinute` set. This is how you can do that:

```
private void showDialog(){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false).show();
}
```

Call this method instead of `showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID)` like that:

```
...
case R.id.intentBtn:
    showDialog();
    break;
...
```

Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot , it worked out:) ... what about the other issue. the calendar doesn't show the correct current time.

Comment: I dont understand, You are talking about timepicker?

Comment: See my edit @Ruba . I did not see your first problem :)

Comment: thanks again. but im still stuck ! there is a 5 hours difference between real time in my laptop and the time appears in the time picker dialog!  minutes are correct. but hours .....if its now 2:30 ,it shows 7:30

Comment: It is your android device's time, not your laptop's time.